How can I get this drop-down menu to display correctly when activated?
here's the site in question:
Irreverent Naturalist
As you can see, when you click on the nav hamburger icon, the bottom menu item is obscured by other page content. Ideally, one of the divs that contains the menu would appear as a 100% opacity white box stretching from the top of the page to a bit below the bottom menu item.
I've tried experimenting with positioning, opacity and z-index, but couldn't get any visible changes at all; have to conclude that I don't understand the way this element is constructed.
I also tried adding this to the CSS
.site-header{ position:relative; z-index:100;}
...which seems to be  positioning the menu items in front of the book cover and header text. However, it's still unreadable. I'd be very ok with an entirely white screen when the nav is open, but that doesn't seem to be happening here.

I also tried adding this code:      .is-menu-open {
min-height: 100vh;
background-color: red;
}          This seems to partially work, in that the menu now appears and takes over the entire screen (I added the red color for visual confirmation it's working, will remove later). However, the menu still won't overlay the other page elements, which is what i'm looking for. I tried adding z-index: 10000 to .is-menu-open, but there was no effect

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?
